# Getting input as hindi character from textbox and storing it to database

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I am using asp.net and c# in my application and Mysql as Database.I want to take input from user in hindi and store it in database and retrieve it.

When I am storing the hindi characters in from Mysql database it is working fine for me but when I am using textbox to input a hindi characters it is showing me ?????????.

I guess the problem is the aspx page does not set to support hindi characters.Please tell me the way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using UTF-8 encoding on your Http request and responses would solve it. What is your `requestEncoding` and `responseEncoding` in your Web.config file set to currently?

See more on the `<globalization>` tag here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Haha.. Oh the memories (and I only had to deal with spanish which fits into the default latin1).

So I don't know the MS side of the stack, but I assume it's the same types of solutions as Java.  Namely you should always assume UTF-8, and thus make your Content-Type HTML responses always show UTF-8 so that browsers know to encode POST data in UTF-8.  You should always inspect the encoding type of HTML POST's just in case you have a browser that ignored the encoding of the HTML form (someone might be using curl/wget/custom-browser).  You need to learn how in MS-land to convert from one encoding type into UTF-8 (in java, for reference, we just say String s = new String(bytes, encoding_name))

Assuming that MS's stack uses UTF-16 or UCS-32 or whatever so that UTF-8 is easy to extract, next comes the mysql layer.

This includes 2 things.. 
1) column encoding MUST be set to UTF8.. It's not obvious at all how to do it, and even the spelling is annoying.. Just google it.. "create database foo default character set UTF8" (approximate syntax), or if you're worried for some reason, do it at the table level "create table foo (..) character set UTF8" (approximate syntax).. Or if the table is already there, take EVERY column that can take arbitrary web-form text (possibly including login-name, but not columns like enumerated varchars - as it would waste index space - even though you'd think it wouldn't) "alter table foo change name varchar(255) character set UTF8" (approximate syntax).

2) You MUST make the ODBC connection (jdbc in java, don't know in MS), encode all in/out characters at UTF-8.  There are two parameters I set (use-unicode, and character-set=UTF-8) (approximate parameter names).

Google it all, but this should point you in the right direction.

Test the existing DB by connecting to mysql both with character-set=UTF8 and latin1.. You'll see totally different output in your text-data when connected as each encoding.  If you're lucky, you already got the data in correctly..  Otherwise you'll have to regenerate ALL the data, or perform some very clever character conversion hacks like I had to do once upon a time (painful stuff).