# Asp.net C# Hindi font in textbox getting converted into numbers and symbol in PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am able to type Hindi characters (words) in my textbox. My textbox post back property is set to true and when the OnTextChanged event is fired then the Hindi characters in the textbox gets converted into symbols and number. Looking for help to sort this.

// Design view :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_Search" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt_Search_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

// Code behind :

```
protected void txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064077/9695286, I hope setting `requestEncoding` & `responseEncoding` to `UTF-8` can solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UTF-8 encoding on Http request is the fix. Setting globalization property in web.config file to this:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, I will. Actually can't accept as resolved in between 23 hours after post.